# Monitor DOM changes and style content with jQuery Mobile and SammyJs

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, sammy.js

I am using jQuery Mobile as a mobile framework. I use jQuery to dynamically populate my pages with custom content. jQuery Mobile does not apply styling to element created after page load. For that reason, I am using

```
$('[data-role=content]').trigger('create');
```

so jQuery Mobile re-evaluates the page styling after my new content has been created.

I also use SammyJs to load the routes and handle the dynamic content creation. I found that if I put the `trigger(create)` inline with my JSON request, the code does not work. However, if I execute the code from a console (adding time between the JSON request and the trigger), jQuery would correctly apply styling...

My workaround is to use `setTimeout` :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('[data-role=content]').trigger('create');
  }, 100);
```

However, I don't feel it is the best solution because the content appears unstyled for miliseconds (user can see it) and then gets refreshed with correct styling...

Is there a way to monitor DOM changes with jQuery mobile or Sammy?

Comment: If you need to monitor DOM changes, why not use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) ?

Comment: I will check but I think it doesn't have a wide implementation?

Comment: True I guess.. maybe you should create a simple jsfiddle to show the actual problem, there probably is a better solution than involving MutationObserver